# Refresh page and combo box #2 contents when combo box #1 changes value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, combobox

I have a problem that I hope you can help/guide me.

I saw a similar question here on stackoverflow but i'm a little more specific about it

here's the previous question

"On php page in a form, One combo box has list of my Customer from mysql table customer. Another combo box has invoiceno stored in invoice table which has respective customer records. I want to select customer from first combo box and filter invoiceno from the second one according to the customer. Any one help me for php or java or Jquery or both codeings? Means if I select customer1 then in the second combo box should show all invoiceno respective to the custermer1. No Refresh or ReLoad or Post form Pl. If I get the first selection in a php variable format example $customer, it is enough for me. Thanks for any one help me."

My idea is the same, but I want to do that in Javascript, questio is how can I do this properly.

Can someone link me or post me an example on how can i do this using javascript? If there's an easy way to do this using other language let me know (ajax for example, i'm not familiar with it.. but i can learn)

I'm population 2 comboboxes using a mysql db

I know how to program in PHP but i'm still learning the basics in javascript.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for: http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/.  If you google 'chained select boxes' you can find some more examples like that one.  You will need to have jquery installed and referenced for the AJAX to work.

Best of Luck

Comment: Omg.. thank you this is exactly what i was looking for. The problem is that english is not my main language, so searching for the right "sentence" is hard sometimes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out jquery. http://jquery.com/

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials  contains some examples for stuff i was also looking for. Thank you for leading me in the right way.